# Fitbit sync with Google Sheet, running into error, Exception

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, fitbit

Found below script online for syncing Fitbit data with Google Sheets using apps script.

```
// interday.gs -- download daily totals from Fitbit
// Doesn't require special permission, just follow setup and authorize
// Original script by loghound@gmail.com
// Modifications - Simon Bromberg (http://sbromberg.com)
// Modifications - Mark Leavitt (PDX Quantified Self organizer) www.markleavitt.com
// Modifications 2020 - Jozef Jarosciak - joe0.com
// https://github.com/qslabs/FitbitDailyData/blob/master/FitbitDailyData.gs
// You are free to use, modify, copy any of the code in this script for your own purposes, as long as it's not for evil
/*
 * Do not change these key names. These are just keys to access these properties once you set them up by running the Setup function from the Fitbit menu
 */
// Key of ScriptProperty for Firtbit consumer key.
var CONSUMER_KEY_PROPERTY_NAME = "fitbitConsumerKey";
// Key of ScriptProperty for Fitbit consumer secret.
var CONSUMER_SECRET_PROPERTY_NAME = "fitbitConsumerSecret";
/*
 * You also need to add the callback URL to your app at dev.fitbit.com in the following format (replace {PROJECT KEY} with your project key:
 * https://script.google.com/macros/d/{PROJECT KEY}/usercallback
 * Go to your app at dev.fitbit.com and click "Edit Application Settings", add the URL in the Callback URL textbox, one URL per line (can do multiple in a single app)
 */
var SERVICE_IDENTIFIER = "fitbit"; // usually do not need to change this either
// Default loggable resources (from Fitbit API docs).
var LOGGABLES = [
  "activities/log/steps",
  "activities/log/distance",
  "activities/log/activeScore",
  "activities/log/activityCalories",
  "activities/log/calories",
  "foods/log/caloriesIn",
  "activities/log/minutesSedentary",
  "activities/log/minutesLightlyActive",
  "activities/log/minutesFairlyActive",
  "activities/log/minutesVeryActive",
  "sleep/startTime",
  "sleep/timeInBed",
  "sleep/minutesAsleep",
  "sleep/awakeningsCount",
  "sleep/minutesAwake",
  "sleep/minutesToFallAsleep",
  "sleep/minutesAfterWakeup",
  "sleep/efficiency",
  "body/weight",
  "body/bmi",
  "body/fat"
];
function getFitbitService() {
  // Create a new service with the given name. The name will be used when
  // persisting the authorized token, so ensure it is unique within the
  // scope of the property store
  if (!isConfigured()) {
    setup();
    return;
  }
  return (
    OAuth2.createService(SERVICE_IDENTIFIER)
      // Set the endpoint URLs, which are the same for all Google services.
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl("https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize")
      .setTokenUrl("https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token")
      // Set the client ID and secret, from the Google Developers Console.
      .setClientId(getConsumerKey())
      .setClientSecret(getConsumerSecret())
      // Set the name of the callback function in the script referenced
      // above that should be invoked to complete the OAuth flow.
      .setCallbackFunction("authCallback")
      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
      .setScope("activity nutrition sleep weight profile settings")
      // but not desirable in a production application.
      //.setParam('approval_prompt', 'force')
      .setTokenHeaders({
        Authorization:
          "Basic " +
          Utilities.base64Encode(getConsumerKey() + ":" + getConsumerSecret())
      })
  );
}
function clearService() {
  OAuth2.createService(SERVICE_IDENTIFIER)
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
    .reset();
}
function showSidebar() {
  var service = getFitbitService();
  if (!service.hasAccess()) {
    var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplate(
      '<a href="<?= authorizationUrl ?>" target="_blank">Authorize</a>. ' +
        "Reopen the sidebar when the authorization is complete."
    );
    template.authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl;
    var page = template.evaluate();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(page);
  } else {
    Logger.log("Has access!");
  }
}
function authCallback(request) {
  Logger.log("authcallback");
  var service = getFitbitService();
  var isAuthorized = service.handleCallback(request);
  if (isAuthorized) {
    Logger.log("success");
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Success! You can close this tab.");
  } else {
    Logger.log("denied");
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Denied. You can close this tab");
  }
}
function getUser() {
  var service = getFitbitService();
  var options = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + service.getAccessToken(),
      /*"oAuthServiceName": SERVICE_IDENTIFIER,
"oAuthUseToken": "always",*/
      method: "GET"
    }
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    "https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/profile.json",
    options
  );
  var o = Utilities.jsonParse(response.getContentText());
  return o.user;
}
function showPrompt() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
  var result = ui.prompt(
    "Let's get to know each other!",
    "Please enter your name:",
    "First Date:",
    "Last Date:",
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL
  );
  // Process the user's response.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();
  var text1 = result.getResponseText();
  var text2 = result.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
    ui.alert("Your name is " + text + ".");
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    // User clicked "Cancel".
    ui.alert("I didn't get your name.");
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // User clicked X in the title bar.
    ui.alert("You closed the dialog.");
  }
}
// function setup accepts and stores the Consumer Key, Consumer Secret, Project Key, firstDate, and list of Data Elements
function setup() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Setup Fitbit Download"); // UiApp API deprecated, may need to eventually replace with HTML service
  var app = HtmlService.createApplication().setTitle("Setup Fitbit Download"); // UiApp API deprecated, may need to eventually replace with HTML service
  app.setStyleAttribute("padding", "10px");
  var consumerKeyLabel = app.createLabel("Fitbit OAuth 2.0 Client ID:*");
  var consumerKey = app.createTextBox();
  consumerKey.setName("consumerKey");
  consumerKey.setWidth("100%");
  consumerKey.setText(getConsumerKey());
  var consumerSecretLabel = app.createLabel("Fitbit OAuth Consumer Secret:*");
  var consumerSecret = app.createTextBox();
  consumerSecret.setName("consumerSecret");
  consumerSecret.setWidth("100%");
  consumerSecret.setText(getConsumerSecret());
  var projectKeyTitleLabel = app.createLabel("Project key: ");
  var projectKeyLabel = app.createLabel(ScriptApp.getProjectKey());
  var firstDate = app.createTextBox().setId("firstDate").setName("firstDate");
  firstDate.setName("firstDate");
  firstDate.setWidth("100%");
  firstDate.setText(getFirstDate());
  var lastDate = app.createTextBox().setId("lastDate").setName("lastDate");
  lastDate.setName("lastDate");
  lastDate.setWidth("100%");
  lastDate.setText(getLastDate());
  // add listbox to select data elements
  var loggables = app
    .createListBox(true)
    .setId("loggables")
    .setName("loggables");
  loggables.setVisibleItemCount(4);
  // add all possible elements (in array LOGGABLES)
  var logIndex = 0;
  for (var resource in LOGGABLES) {
    loggables.addItem(LOGGABLES[resource]);
    // check if this resource is in the getLoggables list
    if (getLoggables().indexOf(LOGGABLES[resource]) > -1) {
      // if so, pre-select it
      loggables.setItemSelected(logIndex, true);
    }
    logIndex++;
  }
  // create the save handler and button
  var saveHandler = app.createServerClickHandler("saveSetup");
  var saveButton = app.createButton("Save Setup", saveHandler);
  // put the controls in a grid
  var listPanel = app.createGrid(8, 2);
  listPanel.setWidget(1, 0, consumerKeyLabel);
  listPanel.setWidget(1, 1, consumerKey);
  listPanel.setWidget(2, 0, consumerSecretLabel);
  listPanel.setWidget(2, 1, consumerSecret);
  listPanel.setWidget(
    3,
    0,
    app.createLabel(" * (obtain these at dev.fitbit.com)")
  );
  listPanel.setWidget(4, 0, projectKeyTitleLabel);
  listPanel.setWidget(4, 1, projectKeyLabel);
  listPanel.setWidget(5, 0, app.createLabel("Start date (yyyy-mm-dd)"));
  listPanel.setWidget(5, 1, firstDate);
  listPanel.setWidget(6, 0, app.createLabel("End date (yyyy-mm-dd)"));
  listPanel.setWidget(6, 1, lastDate);
  listPanel.setWidget(7, 0, app.createLabel("Data Elements to download:"));
  listPanel.setWidget(7, 1, loggables);
  // Ensure that all controls in the grid are handled
  saveHandler.addCallbackElement(listPanel);
  // Build a FlowPanel, adding the grid and the save button
  var dialogPanel = app.createFlowPanel();
  dialogPanel.add(listPanel);
  dialogPanel.add(saveButton);
  app.add(dialogPanel);
  doc.show(app);
}
// function sync() is called to download all desired data from Fitbit API to the spreadsheet
function sync() {
  // if the user has never performed setup, do it now
  if (!isConfigured()) {
    setup();
    return;
  }
  var colIndex = 1;
  var dateColDone = 0;
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  doc.setFrozenRows(4);
  doc.getRange("R1C1").setValue("Sheet last synced: " + new Date());
  doc.getRange("R2C1").setValue("Battery");
  doc.getRange("R3C1").setValue("Last Sync");
  doc.getRange("R4C1").setValue("Date");
  var user = getUser();
  var options = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + getFitbitService().getAccessToken(),
      method: "GET"
    }
  };
  // prepare and end date, and a list of desired data elements
  var dateString = getLastDate();
  var activities = getLoggables();
  // for each data element, fetch a list beginning from the firstDate, ending with today
  Logger.log("here");
  try {
    var devices = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
      "https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/devices.json",
      options
    );
    var device = JSON.parse(devices.getContentText())[0];
  } catch (exception) {
    Logger.log(exception);
    Browser.msgBox("error getting device info for " + user["displayName"]);
  }
  for (var activity in activities) {
    var currentActivity = activities[activity];
    try {
      var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
        "https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/" +
          currentActivity +
          "/date/" +
          getFirstDate() +
          "/" +
          dateString +
          ".json",
        options
      );
    } catch (exception) {
      Logger.log(exception);
      Browser.msgBox("Error downloading " + currentActivity);
    }
    var o = JSON.parse(result.getContentText());
    // set title
    var workingCol = (colIndex + !dateColDone).toString();
    var headerCell = doc.getRange("R1C" + workingCol);
    headerCell.setValue(user["displayName"]);
    headerCell = doc.getRange("R2C" + workingCol);
    if (device != null) {
      headerCell.setValue(device["battery"]);
    } else {
      headerCell.setValue("error no device");
    }
    headerCell = doc.getRange("R3C" + workingCol);
    if (device != null) {
      var syncDate = new Date(device["lastSyncTime"] + "Z");
      headerCell.setValue(
        Utilities.formatDate(syncDate, "GMT", "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm")
      );
    } else {
      headerCell.setValue("error no device");
    }
    var titleCell = doc.getRange("R4C" + colIndex.toString());
    var cell = doc.getRange("R5C" + colIndex.toString());
    // fill the spreadsheet with the data
    var index = 0;
    for (var i in o) {
      // set title for this column
      var title = i.substring(i.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
      titleCell.offset(0, !dateColDone + activity * 1.0).setValue(title);
      var row = o[i];
      for (var j = row.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        var val = row[j];
        if (!dateColDone) {
          cell.offset(index, 0).setValue(val["dateTime"]); // set the date index
        }
        cell
          .offset(index, !dateColDone + activity * 1.0)
          .setValue(val["value"]);
        index++;
      }
    }
  }
  colIndex += 1 + !dateColDone;
  dateColDone = 1;
}
function isConfigured() {
  return getConsumerKey() != "" && getConsumerSecret() != "";
}
// function saveSetup saves the setup params from the UI
function saveSetup(e) {
  setConsumerKey(e.parameter.consumerKey);
  setConsumerSecret(e.parameter.consumerSecret);
  setLoggables(e.parameter.loggables);
  setFirstDate(e.parameter.firstDate);
  setLastDate(e.parameter.lastDate);
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.close();
  return app;
}
function getProperty(key) {
  Logger.log("get property " + key);
  return PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(key);
}
function setProperty(key, value) {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(key, value);
}
function setConsumerKey(consumerKey) {
  setProperty(CONSUMER_KEY_PROPERTY_NAME, consumerKey);
}
function getConsumerKey() {
  var consumer = getProperty(CONSUMER_KEY_PROPERTY_NAME);
  if (consumer == null) {
    consumer = "";
  }
  return consumer;
}
function setConsumerSecret(secret) {
  setProperty(CONSUMER_SECRET_PROPERTY_NAME, secret);
}
function getConsumerSecret() {
  var secret = getProperty(CONSUMER_SECRET_PROPERTY_NAME);
  if (secret == null) {
    secret = "";
  }
  return secret;
}
function setLoggables(loggables) {
  setProperty("loggables", loggables);
}
function getLoggables() {
  var loggable = getProperty("loggables");
  if (loggable == null) {
    loggable = LOGGABLES;
  } else {
    loggable = loggable.split(",");
  }
  return loggable;
}
function setFirstDate(firstDate) {
  setProperty("firstDate", firstDate);
}
function setLastDate(lastDate) {
  setProperty("lastDate", lastDate);
}
function getFirstDate() {
  // var todayDate = new Date;
  var firstDate = subDaysFromDate(new Date(), 60);
  firstDate =
    firstDate.getFullYear() +
    "-" +
    ("00" + (firstDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
    "-" +
    ("00" + firstDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
  return firstDate;
  /*
return firstDate.getFullYear()
+ '-'
+ ("00" + (todayDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
+ '-'
+ ("00" + todayDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
var firstDate = getProperty("firstDate");
if (firstDate == null) {
firstDate = formatToday(); // default value; feel free to change this
}
*/
  //  return firstDate;
}
function getLastDate() {
  var lastDate = subDaysFromDate(new Date(), 0);
  lastDate =
    lastDate.getFullYear() +
    "-" +
    ("00" + (lastDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
    "-" +
    ("00" + lastDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
  return lastDate;
}
function formatToday() {
  var todayDate = new Date();
  return (
    todayDate.getFullYear() +
    "-" +
    ("00" + (todayDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
    "-" +
    ("00" + todayDate.getDate()).slice(-2)
  );
}
function subDaysFromDate(date, d) {
  // d = number of day ro substract and date = start date
  var result = new Date(date.getTime() - d * (24 * 3600 * 1000));
  return result;
}
// function onOpen is called when the spreadsheet is opened; adds the Fitbit menu
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [
    {
      name: "Sync (" + getFirstDate() + " - " + getLastDate() + ")",
      functionName: "sync"
    },
    {
      name: "Setup",
      functionName: "showPrompt"
    },
    {
      name: "Authorize",
      functionName: "showSidebar"
    },
    {
      name: "Reset",
      functionName: "clearService"
    }
  ];
  ss.addMenu("Fitbit", menuEntries);
  /*
SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
.createMenu('Fitbit-New')
.addItem('Show prompt', 'showPrompt')
.addToUi();
*/
}
```

But I keep getting error message:

**Exception: The parameters (String,String,String,String,ButtonSet) don't match the method signature for Ui.prompt.**

any advice would be much appreciated. I found this script here:
https://www.joe0.com/2020/08/02/how-to-sync-fitbit-data-to-google-spreadsheet-vs-2-aug-2020/

Comment: ui prompt has at most 3 parameters I believe [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html#prompttitle,-prompt,-buttons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many parameters here as `prompt` is only expecting three parameters: `title`, `prompt` and `buttons`:

```
function showPrompt() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
  var result = ui.prompt(
    "Let's get to know each other!",
    "Please enter your name:",
    "First Date:",
    "Last Date:",
    ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL
  );
```

A possible way to initiate the modification to showPrompt

```
function showPrompt() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  var r = ui.prompt("Name/FirstDate/LastDate","Please enter your name~firstdate(MM/dd/yyyy)~LastDate(MM/dd/yyyy)",ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if(r.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    let [name,first,last] = r.getResponseText().split("~");
    let firstDate = new Date(first);//should be date objects now
    let lastDate = new Date(last)
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [Ui Class - prompt](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html#prompttitle,-prompt,-buttons).

Comment: if I delete this part would it help to get rid of the error?

Comment: All you have to do is to limit yourself to 3 parameters max. Title, Prompt and ButtonSet

Comment: any chance you can show me what the final script should look like? sorry I don't js

Comment: Sorry I'm not interested in doing the entire script but I provided a portion of showPrompt.  Our scope at this site is limited to answering question and not providing finished scripts for free.